# Rails: Unexpected tSYMBEG error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I found several questions on the same topic but they all have some problem with punctuation(missed or added a comma). In my case, I get the following error when migrating

> SyntaxError: /home/***/workspace/***/app/models/user.rb:27:
>   syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
>   has_many :roles, through :positions

The user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :positions
  has_many :roles, through :positions
end
```

The role model:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :positions
  has_many :users, through :positions
end
```

The position model:

```
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Any idea what might be the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`through` should be a symbol here:

```
has_many :roles, through: :positions
```

and here:

```
has_many :users, through: :positions
```

It is a hash key which is passed to `has_many` method, not a separate method.

[**Documentation**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Comment: My bad, thanks! Will check it as accepted in 8 mins.

Comment: Thanks! I was having a similar issue. I'm glad you were able to answer before this got closed for some reason..